# How to create a file in VS Code with Vim extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Using the [VIM extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) for VSCode, is there a way to create a file inside the folder you are currently selecting on the **explorer** tab?

Similar to how it works with NERDTree on NVIM itself where you can press "a" and it lets you write a filename.

[Brief example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuMSc.png) where the cursor would be placed on the "pages" folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:e <filename>` to create a file and simply use `:w` to save it.

It creates a file in the directory in which your current file is open.  So in the screenshot you provided, if you would be editing `_app.tsx`, the new file will be created in this directory unless differently stated in your filename.